# Impossible to unbind service

Tags: android

I launch my app, the start is called, do the bind service and trigger the onServiceConnected. Everything is ok.

But...

When I press back, onStop is called, my bound var is true as excpected but the onServiceDisconnected is never called...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    Log.e("START", "START");

    super.onStart();

    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    Log.e("STOP", "STOP");

    super.onStop();

    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound)
    {
        this.unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
    {
        Log.e("ON SERVICE START", "ON SERVICE START");

        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocationService.LocationBinder binder = (LocationService.LocationBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0)
    {
        Log.e("ON SERVICE END", "ON SERVICE END");

        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

And my service

```
// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocationBinder();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocationBinder extends Binder
{
    public LocationService getService()
    {
        // Return this instance of LocationService so clients can call public methods
        return LocationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("onBind", "onBind onBind onBind onBind onBind onBind");

    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber()
{
    return new Random().nextInt(100);
}
```

Comment: Does it work properly if you use the HOME button instead of BACK? If so, I would assume that your problem occurs because the activity (the context you've bound the service from) has been destroyed.

Comment: From the documentation: "Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. This does not remove the ServiceConnection itself -- this binding to the service will remain active, and you will receive a call to onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) when the Service is next running." Doesn't sound like it should be called when you unbind from it.

Comment: Ok so 1 hour to understand that's not a bug... Thanks Francesc :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every call to [bindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) should be paired with a call to [unbindService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unbindService%28android.content.ServiceConnection%29).  It actually doesn't matter if the binding worked or not.  The point is to let Android know that you no longer want the connection to be active.  Android will take care of the details of determining if the connection is currently bound and active and taking the appropriate action.

Bottom line is that you should not conditionally call unbindService() here.  Simply always call it in onStop() with the same ServiceConnection that you used when calling bindService() in onStart().

Comment: Ok so 1 hour to understand that's not a bug... Thanks Doug :) !